# Ansible: hostvars keeps returning undefined even if it's defined

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, undefined

This is my shortened inventory file:

```ini
worker01 ansible_host=172.20.15.78 ansible_ssh_user=service ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./variables/dev-cortex-stage/service.pri ansible_ssh_password= ansible_port=22 ansible_ssh_port=22 private_ip=172.20.15.78 worker=true ingress=false storage=true logging=true
```

And this is the playbook:

```yaml
- name: "Taint node '{{ hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] }}'"
  delegate_to: "{{groups['controllers'][0]}}"
  become: true
  shell: "kubectl taint --overwrite=true nodes '{{ hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] }}' storage=true:NoSchedule"
  when: "hostvars['inventory_hostname']['storage'] is defined"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to taint (execute the shell command) when the condition is met but it is never met no matter the way i put the condition. I have even tried `hostvars['inventory_hostname'].storage` but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `hostvars[inventory_hostname]`, `inventory_hostname` needs to be a variable, not a string. This said, what you really want is `when: storage is defined`, because the variables of the current host are available at top level already.

Comment: try to use: `when: storage`

Comment: Hey there guys, I tried running `when: storage and storage is defined` but now the error is: msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'host' is undefined.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce an issue.

Comment: `when: storage | d(false) | bool`

Comment: Or `when: storage is defined and storage` an `and` will stop evaluating as soon as it reaches the first false, from left to right, as `false and ...` will always be `false`. If you put `is defined` as the second expression, for sure it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an inventory file

```ini
[test]
test.example.com storage=true
```

a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} has storage: {{ storage }}"
    when: storage is defined
```

will result into the expected output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: 'test.example.com has storage: true'
```